# Will an iPhone work and still have regular warranty if it's bought outside your country?

Tags: iphone, warranty

I did my research and some sources are saying there wouldn't be warranty if your iPhone is bought outside your home country. But I don't know if that rule still applies now.

I want to buy online on the US apple store 'cause its *waaay* cheaper than where I reside now.

Comment: Could you make it less of an opinionated answer invitation and rather objective facts which can be answered with policies etc as a backup? It will also decrease its chances of getting closed as a shopping recommendation question?

Comment: Okay will edit!!

Comment: Um ... there may be different restrictions based on where you actually live, which is impossible to tell from your question.

Answer (score 0):

If your country has an official Apple store, then yes (warranty covers) but it will not be valid if your country has only the official Apple Reseller store.

You must have a proper purchase bill and verify that you own that hardware, then Apple Store will take care of it. In my case, I had purchased my iPhone in Finland and I was able to get a warranty here in Spain too.

**Offical statement from Apple:**

No Apple reseller, agent, or employee is authorized to make any modification, extension, or addition to this Warranty. If any term is held to be illegal or unenforceable, the legality or enforceability of the remaining terms shall not be affected or impaired. This Warranty is governed by and construed under the laws of the country in which the Apple Product purchase took place. Apple or its successor in title is the warrantor under this Warranty.

Detail on it: https://www.apple.com/legal/warranty/products/ios-warranty-document-us.html

Comment: Country is philippines and we dont have an official apple store. Arent iphones tied in with the serial numbers and they always have one yr warranty?

Comment: You should visit the Offical Apple store of any country nearby you. If your authorized reseller can send the phone to authorized apple store then also it works. But anyway, warranty covers only for Apple Store and Apple Distributor.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, if you buy a SIM-free iPhone, which comes without a wireless contract commitment or carrier financing, then it will work with any nano-SIM from any supported GSM carrier worldwide.

About warranty, it depends on your local Apple Service Provider. Sometimes they might ask for proof of purchase before receiving your device for warranty check.

Comment: Carriers here use gsm. Would there be problems with coverage with lte? It just would work normally? Im paranoid aboit that cause theres no way of testing it until you go to ur countey